# Aligning text with floated img

Tags: css, css-float

What I want to accomplish is for the text to be aligned with the top and left side of the floated img and to wrap immediately underneath with no margin. When I comment out the padding in 'p' the image has no bottom margin, but I want the padding property to be active in my stylesheet.

http://codepen.io/BennyHH/pen/vGxVwz
HTML

```
<div id="box">
  <div id="xob">
  </div>
  <p><!-- Text --></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: silver;
}

#xob {
 width: 50px;
 height: 55px;
 background: blue;
 float: left;
 margin: 15px 15px 0;
}

p {
 padding: 13px 13px 0;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Note: The 'background' tag should read background-color: silver; The background tag has many properties so you need to define one. Color, url, img, etc

Comment: if you want a padding active under the float element, this to this element where padding has to be applied or set as margin, http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/yOMQob else i did not understand your issue. padding of p is only applied inside around the element itself

Comment: Your 'P' class should read .p

Answer (score 0):

It's not *entirely* clear what the intended result is to be but I think you just need negative bottom margin on the image/floated element.

> What I want to accomplish is for the text to be aligned with the top and left side of the floated img and to wrap immediately underneath with no margin.

```css
#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
}
#xob {
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin: 13px;
  margin-bottom: -13px;
}
p {
  padding: 13px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="xob">
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```